# scikit-learn FeatureUnion and multithreading

Tags: multithreading, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have the following transformer:

```
union = FeatureUnion(
    transformer_list = [
     ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
     ('featureEx', FeatureExtractor()),
     ('spell_chker', Spellingchecker()),
     ], n_jobs = -1)
```

The goal here is to run these transformer in parallel on multi-core machine. I have the `n_jobs` option set to -1 for that purpose. When I run the code, there are multiple threads but only one thread is in running mode. The others are in sleep mode. I wonder why only one thread is in running mode. Is it because the subtasks are waiting till one is finished? What should I do to run all the threads in parallel. The transformers are independent to one another and they shouldn't wait each other.

Comment: not sure what you mean by this `there are multiple threads but only one thread is in running mode`

Comment: It should create multiple processes (not threads). Look in task-dispatcher, there must be multiple python processes.

Comment: @Olologin, right multiple processes. I can see those using the `htop` command. So, are not those processes supposed to run at the same time? Why is only one process in running mode while the others are in sleep mode. For me, it looks like the processes are waiting till the first one finished its task.

Comment: Yes, they must work at the same time, because they are
a: independent
b: in different processes.
They will run consequently in python because of GIL only in case when threading backend in joblib is choosen, but it's not true for separated proceses. FeatureUnion exactly uses separated processes for computing.

Maybe you should sort by decreasing S column in htop, to see all [n_cores] active processes, or look at "ps -aux | grep python" command.

Also you should check status only when job is running, thus you should have big dataset, to catch the moment when processes are active.